# recovering from missing session state in ASP.NET MVC with Telerik Ajax

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session, asp.net-mvc-3, telerik

I have a webpage which includes a telerik grid in ajax mode. The data for the grid is constructed in the controller action used to serve the view, and then stored in the session. 90% of the time its available to the ajax method used to populate the grid. And sometimes its not, which is odd. Some sort of race condition ?

```
   public ActionResult EditImage(int productModelId, int revision)
    {
        ViewBag.Current = "Edit";
        //Unit of work and repo generation removed from brevity
        var modelToEdit = prodModelRepo.Where(p => p.ProductModelID == productModelId && p.Revision == revision).FirstOrDefault();
        var vmie = new VMImageEdit(modelToEdit)
                       {
                          //init some other stuff
                       };
        Session["vmie"] = vmie;
        return View(vmie);
    }
```

Now the telerik contorol will post back to _EISelect in order to populate its grid

```
  // Ajax Actions for EditImage
    [GridAction]
    public ActionResult _EISelect()
    {
        var vmie = (VMImageEdit) Session["vmie"];
        return View(new GridModel(vmie.Colours));
    }
```

So if my session object is null, how can I recover  - I guess I need the productModelId and Revision parameters from the original EditImage call. Are they available in the _EISelect in any way - its posted to, and the post contains nothing useful.

Oh to make this possibly harder, this page will be displayed via an inline frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer lies in the telerik ajax databinding - this can be used to pass arbitrary data in the querystring

```
.Select("_EISelect", "AdminProduct", new { productModelId = Model.ProductModelId, revision = Model.Revision})
```

which can be recovered in _EISelect as parameters. Simples.